# How to get regular expression matches between two boundaries

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text:

```
started: Project: ProjectA, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
```

I would like to get just the actual project name which in this example is "ProjectA".

I do have a regular expression `"started:(\s)Project:(\s).*,"`
which will give me `"started: Project: ProjectA,"` and then I can use further basic string searching to return the project name but was wondering if there is any way I can just grab the actual project name without doing the extra string searching, maybe using a correct regular expression.

What I need is the string value between boundaries "started: Project: " and ",".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `started:\sProject:\s(.*),`. I also recommend that you install [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm). This is an excellent tool to debug and analyze regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"started: Project: ([^,]+),"` and then get the value of the first group:

```
var m = regex.Match("....");
string project = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If a project name cannot contain a comma, this should work:

```
started:\sProject:\s(.*?),
```